# Vaadin frontend folder Failed to load content of './frontend/index.html'

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin22

Hi I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4Kin8QTb30) this Alejandro Duarte tutorial from vaadin chanel, but in the third video when I run my code I am having this error when I go to http://localhost:8080

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to load content of './frontend/index.html'. It is required to have './frontend/index.html' file when using client side bootstrapping.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler$IndexHtmlHolder.<init>(IndexHtmlRequestHandler.java:317) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler$IndexHtmlHolder.<init>(IndexHtmlRequestHandler.java:309) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler.lambda$getCachedIndexHtmlDocument$0(IndexHtmlRequestHandler.java:261) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler.getCachedIndexHtmlDocument(IndexHtmlRequestHandler.java:260) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(IndexHtmlRequestHandler.java:81) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1567) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299) ~[flow-server-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109) ~[vaadin-spring-19.0.2.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I am checking this line

`java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to load content of './frontend/index.html'. It is required to have './frontend/index.html' file when using client side bootstrapping.`

It seems like I don't have the frontend folder with the index.html file where it suppose to be

I have a frontend folder in **demo/frontend/index.html**

Also I am seeing another frontend folder in **demo/target/frontend** however this one don't have the index.html file

How can I fix this?

this is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>22.0.1</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.crudui</groupId>
            <artifactId>crudui</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>collaboration-engine</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                        <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

This is how it shows when I run it with `mvn spring-boot:run`

```
------------------ Frontend compilation failed. ------------------

2021-12-11 11:54:37.579  INFO 39073 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Started Webpack. Time: 6075ms
2021-12-11 11:54:37.602  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : ERROR in target/flow-frontend/VaadinDevmodeGizmo.ts:1034:28
2021-12-11 11:54:37.602  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
2021-12-11 11:54:37.602  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1032 |       json = JSON.parse(msg.data);
2021-12-11 11:54:37.602  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1033 |     } catch (e) {
2021-12-11 11:54:37.602  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   > 1034 |       this.handleError(`[${e.name}: ${e.message}`);
2021-12-11 11:54:37.602  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :          |                            ^
2021-12-11 11:54:37.603  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1035 |       return;
2021-12-11 11:54:37.603  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1036 |     }
2021-12-11 11:54:37.603  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1037 |     const command = json.command;
2021-12-11 11:54:37.603  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :
2021-12-11 11:54:37.626  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : ERROR in target/flow-frontend/VaadinDevmodeGizmo.ts:1034:39
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1032 |       json = JSON.parse(msg.data);
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1033 |     } catch (e) {
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   > 1034 |       this.handleError(`[${e.name}: ${e.message}`);
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :          |                                       ^
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1035 |       return;
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1036 |     }
2021-12-11 11:54:37.627  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     1037 |     const command = json.command;
2021-12-11 11:54:37.628  INFO 39073 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :
2021-12-11 12:02:46.371  INFO 39073 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-11 12:02:46.372  INFO 39073 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-11 12:02:46.383  INFO 39073 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 11 ms
2021-12-11 12:02:46.461  INFO 39073 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator  : The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
```

[https://ibb.co/TvsBRxK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5hCc.png)
This is what it shows in the browser

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you try to run it with mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: If you are going to follow Alejandro's example I would recommend to also use Vaadin 21 like he does. Vaadin 22 is brand new and might not work the same way like the example and with the components used.

Comment: I will use it and the will let you know how was everything

Comment: Solved! thanks to @SimonMartinelli and Avec, i have to run it with mvn spring-boot:run and use the same vaadin version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. What i had to do is to check your vaadin addon dependencies and i realised on addon was causing this error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think there must have errors more specific, so I suggest you to look further in your log. I will explain the error I received and what I did. Hope this can help you. By the way, I was watching the same video when I got stuck because the website was not loaded.

What happened
First of all, I'm using VSCode, Maven, Java and all the dependencies of the project (latest versions). After running the App, and accessing localhost:8080 I got the following message (on the browser): "Building front-end development bundle". This message was there for more than 30 minutes. I decided to "Reload the project". It's important to note that this can be done in VSCode without any specific command, just a click. Maybe there's a maven command to do that (mvn clean, mvc compile, mvn install, or else)
After the reload, the App seemed to work fine, without any error message in the console. When I accessed the webpage, it throw almost the same error as your. I went to the terminal and started to analyze the error lines. At some point I identified a key error message: Could not resolve "@vaadin/vaadin-grid/theme/lumo/vaadin-grid-styles.js".
The building of the application created a folder for node in the root folder: node_modules. Inside this folder I found the path indicated by the message, but not the file.
So I searched the web for some clue. Then, I decided to go to the Github repository of Vaadin () to try and find the file. It was not there, but they have the HTML files. Then I decided to compare the HTML file content with the same name with other JS I already had in my folder (I used the vaadin-grid-pro-styles.js as a baseline). As I identified a pattern, I just created the file needed (vaadin-grid-styles.js) using the file "vaadin-grid-styles.html" from the Github repository. Voilà, everything working now.

Here are the links I accessed:

[vaadin-grid-styles.html](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/blob/master/theme/lumo/vaadin-grid-styles.html)

[vaadin-grid-pro-styles.html](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-pro/blob/master/theme/lumo/vaadin-grid-pro-styles.html)

Look for the first WARN or ERROR messages during the build process. Almost forgot, my POM.XML is almost like yours. I think the only differences are the versions I'm using and data specific to my environment (path, project name, Java version, and so on).

Hope this post can help you.